# Show country names on hover for dataless countries in Google GeoChart

Tags: php, jquery, google-visualization

I'm using Google GeoChart to show how many orders we have had from different countries for a particular month.  With the data I'm feeding it, I've got it working all correctly.

However, what I would like to know is if there is a way to show the country name on hover on those that are dataless.

For example, here's some sample data I have:

```
function drawMap() {
        var mapdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Country', 'Orders'],
            ['United Kingdom', 20],
            ['Ireland', 10],
            ['France', 3],
            ['Spain', 3],
            ['Germany', 2],
            ['Norway', 1],
            ['Sweden', 1]
        ]);

        var mapoptions = {
            width: 980,
            colorAxis: {minValue: 0,  colors: ['#6ED0DF', '#3266CC']}
        }

        var mapchart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('mapchart'));
        mapchart.draw(mapdata, mapoptions);
    }
```

As you can see from my sample data, I've got data for a number of European countries so when the map is rendered on the screen, it will show the country name when you hover over those above.  However, when I hover over Belgium or Poland (for example), the map doesn't show the name of the country.

Is there a way to show this?  Ideally, I don't want to list ALL countries in mapdata - is there a function I can run that will show the other countries names?  Even if it has to say 0 or N/A for the data...

Just for reference, I'm using PHP to get the data we need to populate the map from a MySQL database.

Comment: There is no internal magic google function to do what you want. You can create a list of all countries to check against your database, and set each to zero. Or you can use a lookup to update values in your array for countries with data, and leave the others as a default zero.

Comment: I thought as much! I think I'll create an array of country names from all that we deliver to, set the default value to be zero and then replace that if that country appears for that particular month :)